# Create Cosmos DocumentDB trigger programmatically and fire event when changed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DocumentDB that is being written to by a separate process. I need to know (in my own process) when the content in that DocumentDB changes.

It would be great if it would fire off a local event so I could process the data.

I have been looking in to `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Trigger` to do this, but can't seem to wire it up to raise a local event when this happens.

Should I use a different mechanism other than Trigger to accomplish this? Or can I use a Trigger? If so, how?

This is more-or-less a way of doing IPC -- I am trying to avoid polling the DocumentDB for changes.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of research, it turns out I needed to implement [change feed support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed), specifically using the [Change Feed Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#change-feed-processor) library.

If anyone thinks this may be overkill or can come up with a better solution, I am all ears. There just isn't much about this online though.